# Export all events from a shared calendar, including events added by non-owners

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to extract Google Calendar event data into a spreadsheet, which works. However, the code I use only exports data which has been created by the owner of the Google Account/Calendar, not events that have been added by other users.

Below is a sample of some of the code I am using to get to the calendar and to retrieve events details.

Is there any way of achieving the above with details added by all users..?

```
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("name of calendar");
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("18/08/2018 12:00 AM"), new Date("30/08/2018 12:00 AM"))
```

---

**Edit**:

Further to my original post, this may help..

Thanks for the replies so far... I'm not entirely sure what is going on in the code that has just been quoted, my full function is below. It may also help too if I give the practical example of what I'm trying to do.

A warehouse moves in /out a number of pallets each day. Details of these various in/outs are added as events on the "in" and "out" calendars. One calendar for each type of operation. Details are only entered into the "Title" section (e.g. PO numbers, etc.) and a time given. I had the idea of putting the number of pallets into the "Description" section so that when we extract events into a spreadsheet, we get a count of pallets in and out, each day, hour, etc.

```
function goodsin() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("name of calendar");

  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("18/08/2018 12:00 AM"), new Date("30/08/2018 12:00 AM"));
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {                        
    var title = events[i].getTitle();
    var sd = events[i].getStartTime();
    var ed = events[i].getEndTime();
    var des = events[i].getDescription();

    ss.getRange(i+2, 1).setValue(title)
    ss.getRange(i+2, 2).setValue(sd);
    ss.getRange(i+2, 2).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM")
    ss.getRange(i+2, 3).setValue(ed);
    ss.getRange(i+2, 3).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM")
    ss.getRange(i+2, 4).setValue(des);
  }
}
```

Comment: You might need to use the actual Calendar API and not just the Calendar Service `CalendarApp`. Have you looked at -in detail- the `CalendarApp` methods to see if any of them come even close to offering or suggesting something akin to what you ask for? Because (to me) knowing about events you are attending or invited to should be queryable...

Comment: Thanks you for the reply.  i have checked through the list on the webpage to see if any descriptions match to what im looking for but as im sort of new to this, nothing has jumped out at me.. Some methods have Options but in a [ ] field. But im not sure what options there are to put in the argument ...

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your issue.

#### Events in "default" calendars

Using account A, I created an event on its default calendar, and invited account B. Account B has not accepted the invitation.

From account B, if I run the following code, I get the event information in my Stackdriver logs:

```
function getNextEvent_(calendars) {
  if (!calendars)
    calendars = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  const now = new Date();
  const end = new Date();
  return calendars.map(function (cal) {
    var weeks = 4;
    end.setTime(now.getTime());
    do {
      end.setDate(end.getDate() + 7)
      var e = cal.getEvents(now, end, {max: 1}).pop();
    } while (!e && --weeks);
    return cal.getName() + ': ' +
      (!e
       ? 'No visible events up to ' + end.toLocaleString()
       : e.getTitle() + ' (Org. by ' + e.getCreators().join(',') + ')'
      );
  });
}
function logNextEvents() {
  console.log({
    message: "Upcoming Events",
    events: getNextEvent_()
  });
}
```

If I dig deeper, the event is found for the default calendar of Account B, i.e. `CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEvents(...)` contains the event owned and organized by Account A.

#### Events in a shared calendar

Setup:

1. Account A makes a new Google Calendar.
2. Account B is added with the permission to make changes to events.
3. Account C is added with the permission to make changes to events.
4. All accounts create an event on the calendar (3 events created).

Code:

```
function querySharedCal() {
  const id = 'notarealgroupid@group.calendar.google.com';
  const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id);
  if (!cal) throw new Error("no calendar");
  const now = new Date();
  const end = new Date();
  end.setDate(end.getDate() + 4);
  const events = cal.getEvents(now, end).map(function (e) {
    return cal.getName() + ': ' + e.getTitle() + 
      ' (Org. by ' + e.getCreators().join(',') + ')';
  });
  console.log({message:"search result by " + Session.getTemporaryActiveUserKey(), events: events});
}
```

Cases:

- Account A runs the above code
- Account B runs the above code
- Account C runs the above code

Results:

- All cases return the 3 events. Even if each of the accounts a, b, c writes their own code (rather than having a single project which each can execute), all queries are successful.

---

Perhaps there is something you aren't sharing with us regarding the permission levels of the calendar, the accounts that create the events, the event visibilities, and the account from which you perform the queries.